# FFmpeg doesn't take input while overwrite question

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, zenity

My script basicly do convert videos (ex: mp4 --> mkv). Let's say there is a video file in working directory with name "1.mp4" and we want to create a new file "2.mkv". In this case script runs withour error. But if I try to "1.mp4 --> 2.mkv" again, `FFmpeg` asks me that "2.mkv already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] "
Normally I could answer that. But in this situation I cannot give `FFmpeg` an input. And because of this it says "Not overwriting - exiting". After that my program looks for the `if` situtation and try `zenity` commands.

Here's the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

CONTROL(){
    case $? in
        1)
        exit 1;;
        5)
        clear
        echo "Program Closed: Timed Out (15)."
        exit 5;;
        -1)
        clear
        echo "An Unexpected Error Has Occurred."
    esac
}

NOINFO(){
    if [ -z "$ACODEC" ]; then ACODEC="copy"; fi
    if [ -z "$VCODEC" ]; then VCODEC="copy"; fi
    if [ -z "$EXTE" ]; then EXTE=${FNAME##*.}; fi
    EXTE=${EXTE##*.}
}

FNAME=$(zenity --file-selection \
--title="[1/2] Select a Video File" 2> /dev/null)
CONTROL

VAR=$(zenity --forms --separator=":" \
--title="[2/2] Required Informations" \
--text="Enter the required informations.\nFor defaults just click OK." \
--add-entry="Audio Codec (Default = copy)" \
--add-entry="Video Codec (Default = copy)" \
--add-entry="Output Extension (Default = Input)" 2> /dev/null)
CONTROL

ACODEC=$(echo "$VAR" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
VCODEC=$(echo "$VAR" | cut -d ":" -f 2)
EXTE=$(echo "$VAR" | cut -d ":" -f 3)
NOINFO

sudo ffmpeg -i "$FNAME" -c:a "$ACODEC" -c:v "$VCODEC" "$FNAME.$EXTE"

if zenity --text-info --title="Confirm" \
    --checkbox="I want to delete the original file." 2> /dev/null
then
    sudo rm "$FNAME" && sudo mv "$FNAME.$EXTE" "${FNAME%.*}.$EXTE"
fi

zenity --question --width="200" --timeout="15" --title="Please Answer" \
--text="Continue?" 2> /dev/null
CONTROL
```

How can I give the program inputs?

Comment: Please stop using UPPER CASE VARIABLES, they are reserved for system use

Comment: Oh thanks never never thought about it.

Comment: ffmpeg has an option -y, which is equivalent to answering y.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is helpful, but is there a way to give inputs for another situations?